# Why doesn't hook_preprocess_block() alter the block content?

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm finding I can't alter block content with hook_preprocess_block() in Drupal 8.  Should I expect to be able to alter content, such as a block body, using hook_preprocess_block()?

For example, this has no effect on my block output:

```
function mysite_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['elements']['content']['body'][0]['#text'] = 'alter all block bodies everywhere';
}
```

Comment: first check blocks are of which type,view block or  custom block ,if its view block then above preprocess function will not work

Comment: You need to look at which variables the template uses to determine which ones you need to alter. In the default template it comes from "content", not elements.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong --  Thanks.  Yes, it's as simple as dropping that 'elements' key.  This works: $variables['content']['body'][0]['#text'].  Somehow I couldn't find the right combination the other day.

Comment: @Vikram8888 -- Thanks.  That is a very good thing to keep in mind as well.

Comment: May be worth noting that setting a value in hook_preprocess_block() for $variables['content']['body'][0]['#text'] only works -- at least in my case -- if there is a value saved in the body field.  One of the reasons I struggled with this initially is that I had nothing saved in the body field in the database, but was still trying to set a value for the field in hook_preprocess_block().  Solved by saving some dummy characters to the body field.

Comment: @Vikram8888 - how can I preprocess a view block then? I want to reorder the output of a list in the views facet block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues, in my case.  For one thing, I was using the wrong key.  I needed to use...

```
$variables['content']['body'][0]['#text']
```

...instead of...

```
$variables['elements']['content']['body'][0]['#text']
```

The other issue was that I had nothing saved in the body field, and in some cases setting a value for the body field in hook_preprocess_block() has no effect on output unless there is a value saved in the body field.  You must at least save some garbage characters to the field or else setting a value in hook_preprocess_block() will have no effect on the output.